# Simple function to list only sub directories within a directory

Tags: php, function, dirname

Newb here

I'm attempting to craft a simple function that will create a simple list of all the subdirectories available within a directory.

My code currently returns all the names of the subdirectories but it also returns all the names of the files in the directory which i do not want.

```
function getDirectories(){
    echo "Directories available:<br />";

    foreach (glob("*") as $dirname ) {
    echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$dirname \">$dirname</a><br />";}
    }
```

Comment: its my goal to show all folders within the directory, not necessarily to show the folders within the folders though. This is just to be a simple little index tool for my local server when i'm working and updating and trying various versions of files so i don't have to type the url in to the browser constantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look over here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

```
if( is_dir( $dirname ) ) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked once i figured out how to work with it. And also thank you for the suggested pages on php.net - i didn't find that when searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob` function with `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag.

```
glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: This is interesting, but i couldn't figure out how to properly implement it.

Comment: In foreach loop instead of your glob function usage.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this work when i tried placing it in, near and around my foreach loop. I tried it with and without the semicolon. I got various errors